# How to get the name of the file that the user can download?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, download, fileresponse

I have a django view that returns a FileResponse

```
return FileResponse(protected_pdf_file, as_attachment=True, filename='result.pdf')
```

I am getting this response using ajax -

```
function ajaxSend(url, data) {
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (content_type === 'application/json') {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                return response.blob();
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            if (data instanceof Blob) {
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(data);
                download_link.href = url;

                // download_link.download = ...

                download_link.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                block_msg.textContent = data.message;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

Where **"download_link.download = ..."** I need to substitute the file name.

I tried to get the file name - `const contentDisposition = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');`, but contentDisposition is **null** as a result.

Please tell me how to get the name of the file returned from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function ajaxSend(url, data) {
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (content_type === 'application/json') {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                const contentDisposition = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
                const parts = contentDisposition.split(';');
                fileName = parts[1].split('=')[1];
                return response.blob();
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            if (data instanceof Blob) {
                // You can use fileName here

                const url = URL.createObjectURL(data);
                download_link.href = url;

                // download_link.download = ...

                download_link.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                block_msg.textContent = data.message;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

Also remember to set `headers = {'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition'}`, and then add it to your `FileResponse(protected_pdf_file, as_attachment=True, filename='result.pdf', headers=headers)`